# IndexedDB, How to get updated data without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, localforage

I am using angular-localforage and I have some key in my IndexedDB. When i do set new value to my key it still seems with previous value, since i reload the page and it seems with the latest value.

Is there any solution to get updated data without reloading the page?

```js
$scope.addToStage = function($index) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log($scope.items[$index].title);

  $localForage.getItem('stage').then(function(data) {
    if (data) {
      $localForage.removeItem('stage');
      console.log('Item stage Removed!');
    };
    $localForage.setItem('stage', $scope.items[$index]).then(function(data) {
      $localForage.bind($scope, 'stage');
    }) //setItem
  })

  $ionicHistory.clearCache();
  $state.reload();
  $ionicHistory.goBack();
};
```

** Although I think it is not my code fault, since when i adding  new items or removing theme using setItem() and removeItem() need a page reload to see changes in Developer Tools's Resources.

** As mentioned in [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API): IndexedDB originally included both an asynchronous API and a synchronous API; But the synchronous version was removed from the spec because its need was questionable. So I think my question has not any absolute answer at this time maybe, BTW any resources, articles and links come helpful. :)

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @FrEaKmAn issue updated. other codes needed?

Comment: ** Although I think it is not my code fault, since when i adding new items or removing theme using setItem() and removeItem() need a page reload to see changes in Developer Tools's Resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a test code

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['LocalForageModule']);
app.config(['$localForageProvider', function($localForageProvider)
{
   $localForageProvider.config({
        driver      : localforage.INDEXEDDB, // if you want to force a driver
        name        : 'myApp', // name of the database and prefix for your data, it is "lf" by default
        version     : 1.0, // version of the database, you shouldn't have to use this
        storeName   : 'keyvaluepairs', // name of the table
        description : 'some description'
    });
}]);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$localForage', function($scope, $localForage) 
{
    $scope.load = function()
    {
        $localForage.getItem('name').then(function(data) 
        {
            console.log('Loaded ' + data + ' from DB');
            $scope.name = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.save = function()
    {
        console.log('Saved ' + $scope.name + ' to DB');
        $localForage.setItem('name', $scope.name).then(function(){});
    };

    $scope.refresh = function()
    {
        $scope.load();
    };

    $scope.load();
}]);
```

and the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello <input ng-model="name" type="text" /><button ng-click="save()">save</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <button ng-click="refresh()">refresh</button>
</div>
```

Full jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kzwtyn2c/

You can save the name and when you hit the refresh button, it will log the value retrieved from the database.

Everything works, but it seems that Chrome Developer Tools are not updating. Even if you right click on the IndexedDB table and click Refresh IndexedDB the value does not change.

In my case, it changed if I reloaded the Developer Tools (so hide them and show again). It's a workaround, but I presume it's a bug.